# Systemd configuration in YugabyteDB k8s deployment

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

In this doc: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/manual-deployment/system-config/#ntp, it mentions:

> If you're using systemd to start the processes…

If YugabyteDB is deployed on k8s with helm chart, under the hood, is yb-master / yb-follower started using systemd?

Second question:
the above instruction is located under "Manual Deployment" section of the doc. In the k8s deployment section: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/kubernetes/single-zone/oss/yugabyte-operator/ there are no instructions on "system configuration".

I am wondering, we still want to configure each node for "system configuration", the helm chart deployment won't set those ulimits for us, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most containers don't have systemd, the entrypoint yb-master/yb-tserver processes are started directly by the container runtime.
Good point that the node preparation should ideally set the ulimits if you are preparing your own kubernetes cluster.

Typically, ulimits on most cloud kubernetes clusters like GKE/EKS are set to reasonable values. Ulimits can generally not be set from within pods directly unless they are privileged pods.

Since yb containers don't have systemd, there is no need to configure /etc/systemd/system.conf.